# android-How to check location is in special area?

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

I want to use google map in my android app in specific area. for example in special country. How can I check that my current location is in that place?

**updates:**

for example how to check that I am in New Delhi city

Comment: Didn't get your question..please explain it properly

Comment: There seems to be a public webservice somewhere which will tell you. Otherwise you need a polygon which defines the border of the country and check if position is within this geofence..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using `LatLngBounds` and `LatLngBounds.contains()`

```
private LatLngBounds NewDelhi = new LatLngBounds(your special area SE LatLng , NE LatLng );

if(NewDelhi.contains(your location LatLng)) 
//Do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Get city name from [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
//String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
//String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

For more: [Displaying a Location Address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)